# Unknown Action exception : Routing Error in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

I have the following two lines in default routes

```
  match '/:controller/:action'
  match '/*path' , :to => 'map#catch_all'
```

So the issue is, when user hit the valid controller and invalid action name like **/user/aaaa** then got and exception of "Unknown action" because the route got catched by the first line of above mentioned routes.
I can't change the order of the above lines either.

Any help??
All comments are appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In production you should not allow the user to access not explicitly allowed actions. You should enumerate all available action, or use resource to allow the restful paths automatically. This will solve your problem.

Also, if unmatched url is entered, then the 404 message will appear to the user, which is the right way of handling this.

**UPDATE:**
In your ApplicationController you can implement the `method_missing(method, *args)` method, to handle all the non-existing action calls which may come from the wildcarded routes.

```
def method_missing(method, *args)
  # handle Unknown Action
end
```

But be aware, that this catches all method call which is not existing, and this can cause problem with debugging for example in case of a typo.

Comment: Your points are valid but i have lil different case. I have a huge code base so can enumerate all the controller/actions. The second line is doing exactly the what you suggested, it hit to the catch_all action and render 404 in production. But the issue is, when you hit valid controller name

Comment: The UnknowAction error is handled in the dispatcher middleware. You need some workaround to handle the not existing actions. What is the problem with the 404 page?

Comment: No problem with 404 page, it got displayed successfully when user hits Invalid Controller and invalid Action, but an o0o0ps exception occurs when user hits valid Controller and Invalid ACtion..

Comment: Have you tried using `method_missing(method, *args)` to catch the invalid actions in the application controller? Not a good solution, but it can work. Or write a script which enumerates all your controller/action routes. :)

Comment: will try it, but i dont think it will get invoked whenever there is some Routing exception.

Comment: what about the solution provided by Neeraj Singh at https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4444-can-no-longer-rescue_from-actioncontrollerroutingerror

Comment: I though about linking this, but I was not sure if its working properly or not. Worths a try anyway. :) But don't forget, that this will override every kind of exception rendering.

Comment: method_missing(method, *args) awesomingly working. Thanks, Please edit your answer as per your comment so that i can mark it as answer, just to avoid visitors to go though these comments

Comment: It worked great @Matzi :) Note:'method_missing' is deprecated now and will be removed from rails 4.0. Use 'action_missing' instead. Please update your answer accordingly.